# Github: Disable notifications for Pull Request events only

Tags: github

## Goal

I don't want to receive notifications about Pull Request events for our main repository.

## Use Case

Once the PR is assigned to me via another project management tool I will read all the PR comments anyway. There's no need for me to get notified about every single comment cause there's no action required from me at that moment. Notifications about new PR events in this repository are just noise to me.

## Current options (AFAIK)

1. Click "unsubscribe"-link in first notification for a new PR.
2. Ignore all events for the repository.

Currently I'm doing 1. but am strongly considering using 2.

Unfortunately I don't want to miss out on standard commit comments when co-workers try to gain context in a given piece of code that changed in the past.

## Question

Is there another way for me to disable notifications for PR events in this repository? Some sort of setting I don't know about?

Comment: I can't believe (1) the Github notifications are in this state, (2) nobody else is bothered by this, as evidenced by (3) no one upvoting or answering this question. This situation frustrates me at least once a month, if not once a week.